# Converting half-with and full-with CJK latin-like characters to ASCII in Java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

My application takes an input from the user. Some of the Asian user enter text with  latin-like characters but encoded with Unicode range U+FF01–FF5E.
When I try to compare this input strings with something in ASCII they are not equal (as expected).

Here is Wikipedia article about the characters range http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms

How do I convert characters from that range to ASCII equivalents?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the *only* characters you need to convert, you could use:

```
String convertLatinLikeToAscii(String text) {
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (c >= 0xff01 && c <= 0xff5e) {
            // Map U+FF01 to U+0021 etc
            chars[i] = (char) (c - (0xff01 - 0x21));
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, cause the left byte starts with a 1 bit, which means in UTF-16 that there are more bytes coming. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: No, I don't believe UTF-16 works like that. The only cases where a Unicode code point takes more than one UTF-16 code unit is for surrogate pairs, IIRC. Perhaps you were thinking of UTF-8, where the top-bit of a byte being set *does* mean that more bytes are required to form a code unit? A UTF-16 code unit is *always* two bytes. (It's variable-length in that it can require two code units for one code point, but the size of each code *unit* is fixed.)

Comment: Yup, I though UTF-16 worked exactly the same way, but it doesn't, I see. Thanks again! :) The design of UTF-16 is smarter than I thought.

Comment: we could also change the space character that uses U+3000 by adding the followign code:

         if (c == 0x3000 ){
          chars[i] = 0x20;
         }

Comment: @Slav: There are probably a bunch of similar things you may wish to do - hence my first sentence :) I don't know enough about other places you'd want to convert though.